# Will a black hole's gravity disappear if this black hole is big enough?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes

Suppose gravitation comes from the certain particle in an atom, suppose its name is X particle. if this black hole keeps growing, and his gravity grows continuously. Until a certain moment, in the centre of black hole, the gravity is so large that all of X particles are crushed and destroyed, at this moment, all of the material in the centre part will lost their gravity. Am I right?

Comment: If this were true, black holes would not have gravitational forces.

Comment: *"Suppose gravitation comes from the certain particle in an atom"* Why would we suppose that? Gravitation comes from [stress-energy-momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be imagining that particles sort of collect in a ball at the center of a black hole, stay there for some time, and then are eventually crushed when the black hole gets big enough. This is not really right for a bunch of reasons.

All black holes have singularities, not just big ones.

The singularity is not a point at the center, it's a spacelike surface which can only lie in the future of an observer.

An object that falls into a typical-sized black hole reaches the singularity in a matter of milliseconds, according to a clock attached the the object. In classical gravity, this means that the object is basically immediately destroyed. It's destroyed when it reaches the singularity.

An observer outside the black hole can't say whether the singularity has already formed or will form at some point in the future. General relativity doesn't have a notion of simultaneity that defines that. However, the gravitational field of the black hole never decreases, regardless of whether you imagine that matter has "already" hit the singularity.

Comment: From your statement "An observer outside the black hole can't say whether the singularity has already formed or will form at some point in the future."  The observer is looking at black hole.  Your statement means that there is in existence a black hole, possibly without a singularity.  Can you explain how that is possible?

Comment: @dllahr: *Your statement means that there is in existence a black hole, possibly without a singularity.* When you want to say whether a singularity exists "now," you need some notion of simultaneity. GR doesn't provide that.

Comment: @safesphere: Yes, you're correct that a singularity is not a surface in the sense of being a point-set in the spacetime manifold. There are specialized definitions to get around this, so that we can talk about things like whether a singularity is timelike or spacelike. Your description of it as a line removed from the manifold is incorrect. Topologically, the Schwarzschild spacetime is trivial; if it were as you describe, the spacetime would have a different topology.

Comment: @ben crowell  I'm not positing simultaneity.  I am pointing out the existence of black holes which have been observed and measured now and in the past. How could these exist without a singularity?

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly in the form of particles as you described, but with big enough mass, the quantum space time speculates that somehow, the inward gravity would blink for a moment resulting into an explosion (big bang). This would predict a cyclic universe instead of rips or freezes. Watch this 2019 video from 36:50 to 41:00 - https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=what+is+space+time+and+how+it+works